# Using D language binding for Xamarin Studio on Mac

Tags: d, xamarin-studio

Following the instructions from here http://wiki.dlang.org/Mono-D to setup Xamarin Studio (5.9.3) on Mac for D Development. When trying to run a simple Hello World programm I get this error however:

`Native error= Cannot find the specified file`

I left the Defaults for the D environment settings except for the Toolchain bin path which is pointing to the bin of the dmd compiler on my system.
`/usr/share/dmd/bin`

The Program works fine when executed from the Command Line. Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you have dub installed and set to the correct path in Mono-D?

Comment: I didn't but I tried that now and got the same error. I set the path to the executable in D/Dub Options/dub executable, that's what you meant right?. In the Mono-D wiki it also said dub was optional..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to export dub onto your shell path. If I remember correctly (sorry, year or so since I left my MacBook) the default path for dub is just 'dub' in Xamarin so there is an expectation of it being on the path.